# Docker is copying the context dir into my workdir

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this very simple image:

```
FROM node:11-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY src /app/src

RUN cd src \
    && npm i --no-cache \
    && npm run build

CMD cd src \
    && npm run start
```

Everything is ok during the build, e.g. a simple `ls -R /` reveals the following  tree:

```
/:
app/

/app:
src/

/app/src:
package.json ...
```

But when I try to start it I find the following structure:

```
/:
app/

/app/:
src/

/app/src/:
src/ ... more files from the context dir that I never COPYed

/app/src/src/:
package.json ...
```

If I `RUN ls -R /` just after `npm run build` I get the 'good' tree, even running `ls -R /` just one layer before `CMD` I get the same 'good' tree, but any layer after CMD (including CMD itself) gets me the 'wrong' tree, e.g:

```
CMD ls -R / && cd src && npm run start
```

It shows `/app/src/src`, just as if it was taking all the contents of the context dir and putting them below the `WORKDIR/src` (i.e. `/app/src`)

Why is docker doing this?

I'm running

> Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
>
> docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad0

Comment: You mention Docker Compose; is there a `volumes:` section in your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around in a somewhat "cleaner" environment at home, I found out that, as a comment suggests, the culprit was a stuck volume, it was mounting `./myapp:/app/src` even though such thing was no longer around in the volumes section of my `docker-compose.yaml` file, and a simple yes|docker system prune did the trick.